# How do you solve this problem

Tags: microeconomics

[image]

How do you solve this exchange economy problem?

Answer (score 2):

(a) To find the competitive equilibrium, we first find the demands. Utility maximisation problem of consumer $i$ is
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_i\geq 0, y_i\geq 0} & \sqrt{x_i} + y_i\\ \text{s.t. } & px_i+y_i\leq 8p+10\end{eqnarray*}
Solving this problem, we get $i$'s demand for commodity $x_i$ as:
\begin{eqnarray*} x_i(p) = \min\left\{\dfrac{1}{4p^2},\dfrac{8p+10}{p}\right\} \end{eqnarray*}
We can now solve for the competitive equilibrium price $p$ by equating demand for $X$ and with supply of $X$ i.e. using $x_A(p)+x_B(p)+x_C(p)=24$, and we get $p = \dfrac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}$. Corresponding competitive equilibrium allocation is the endowment itself i.e. each consumer $i$ consumes $(x_i,y_i)=(8,10)$. This equilibrium is also Pareto efficient because the environment in the problem satisfies the conditions for the First Welfare Theorem to hold.

(b) In this part we have an exchange economy with externalities. Competitive equilibrium in this case requires consumers to solve the following problems:
Utility maximisation problem of consumer $A$ is
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_A\geq 0, y_A\geq 0} & \sqrt{x_A} + \sqrt{x_B}+ y_A\\ \text{s.t. } & px_A+y_A\leq 8p+10\end{eqnarray*}
Utility maximisation problem of consumer $B$ is
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_B\geq 0, y_B\geq 0} & \sqrt{x_A} + \sqrt{x_B}+ y_B\\ \text{s.t. } & px_B+y_B\leq 8p+10\end{eqnarray*}
Utility maximisation problem of consumer $C$ is
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_C\geq 0, y_C\geq 0} & \sqrt{x_C}+ y_C\\ \text{s.t. } & px_C+y_C\leq 8p+10\end{eqnarray*}
Observe that each consumer $i$'s demand for $x_i$ is same as before i.e.
\begin{eqnarray*} x_i(p) = \min\left\{\dfrac{1}{4p^2},\dfrac{8p+10}{p}\right\} \end{eqnarray*}
Using demand equal supply, we get the same equilibrium as before i.e. $p = \dfrac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}$ and the corresponding competitive equilibrium allocation is also the endowment itself i.e. each consumer $i$ consumes $(x_i,y_i)=(8,10)$. However, competitive equilibrium in this case is not Pareto efficient. This is because allocation $(x_A,y_A)=(x_B,y_B)=\left(\frac{32}{3},9.4\right)$ $(x_C,y_C)=\left(\frac{8}{3},11.2\right)$ is Pareto superior to it.

(c) Set of interior Pareto efficient allocations are all feasible allocations that satisfy $x_A=x_B=\frac{32}{3}$, $x_C=\frac{8}{3}$.

There are also corner Pareto efficient allocations such as allocations where $y_C=0$. These are the feasible allocations where $x_C\leq\frac{8}{3}$, and $x_A=x_B=\frac{24-x_C}{2}$.

Likewise, there are corner allocations where $y_A=0$ and/or $y_B=0$. Try to find those.